# Description list make terms dynamic width, descriptions static width

Tags: html, css, list

I'm creating a description list. I want the terms and the descriptions to line-up horizontally. Also I want the term to be of dynamic width, but the description to be of a static width.

What I want to achieve:

[image: Description list style I want to achieve]

Here is a JSFiddle to start with:
https://jsfiddle.net/n14bobma/

```
<dl>
    <dt>term 1</dt>
    <dd>desciption 1</dd>

    <dt>term 2</dt>
    <dd>desciption 2</dd>

    <dt>term 3</dt>
    <dd>desciption 3</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Only if you wrap each pair in the markup, or use JS I think.

Comment: Use a table, to align the description to the larger term. Your structure will be close to what you have.

Comment: A <dl> tag van only hold <dt> and <dd> tags, according to W3C: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/dl.html#dl. So wrapping each pair won't be an option.

Comment: @fbiazi but I want to use a description list, since my data will be terms and descriptions of those terms.

Comment: That is not possible with CSS, _because_ of the way definition lists are structured. There is no “connection” between the `dt`/`dl` pairs, and therefor you can not make the width of the widest `dt` affect the width of all other terms as well. You need to either use JS, to measure the natural widths of all terms to find the max value and then set that as explicit width on all terms – or another HTML structure.

Comment: I finally changed it to a table. It is not possible with CSS, like @CBroe said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally changed from a description list to a table. However, when the dl can be the full width of his parent, we found a solution which works when you align the list right on the page(which was our case). See this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n14bobma/1/

This is the CSS we used:

```
dt, dd {
    display: inline-block;

    text-align: right;
}

dt {width: calc(100% - 100px);}
dd {width: 100px;}
```

We used CSS calc to make the `<dt>`'s of dynamic with. For IE8 and older Android browsers you can write some kind of fallback with percentages.